# Laravel Passport Custom Password Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I want to override how passport compare user input password and saved password. I have my own encrypt/decrypt function to generate and verify password and i want passport to use my decrypt function to verify password.

I have tried this solution https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#customizing-the-password-validation but doesn't work at all.

Is there any way to implement this? i want it to be like this

```
public function validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password)
{
    return customDecrypt($this->password) == $password;
}
```

But the method validateForPassportPasswordGrant seems never called. Thanks

```
"laravel/framework": "^6.2",
"laravel/passport": "^8.2",
```

Comment: `but doesn't work at all.` - what about it doesn't work?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - for example, put dd() in it and it won't work. Like it's not called at all